# Power steering went out and temperature gauge running hot

Tags: jeep, power-steering, power

We have a 2016 Jeep Compass. The temperature gauge goes all the way to H and the power steering went out. We put power steering fluid in but it's still really hard to turn.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Make sure you haven’t over-filled your fluids! Not sure about your PS system specifically, but some systems will sustain damage from being over-filled! That said, I agree with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that your question should be edited so that it’s clear what you’re asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you should check the drive belt : it would be the common link for the two issues occurring at the same time as you describe.

On most engines, the one belt does all the ancillaries power steering, air-con, water pump and alternator - one reason why the belts are so long as well. Long gone are the days when engine had 3 or 4 belts one for this, one for that...